# pandas - newline char splitting row in multiple rows while reading and writing csv

Tags: python, pandas

My task is to read a CSV file from one location, do some manipulation in memory in dataframe and then place file at some other location.

The source file is '||' seperated, and target file has to be "," seperated.

I have do this for multiple files, with different columns.

In one of the source csv, one of the column contains new line char within the column.

example source CSV file:

```
id||notes<CR><LF>
1||notesLine1<CR><LF>
2||notesLine1<CR><LF>
notesLine2<CR><LF>
3||notesLine1: notesLine2<CR><LF>
```

note that line seperator is also  and new line chars within the column 'note' is also .
I cannot change the source, however I can have a mid layer in memory or disk if any modification is required.

code:

```
...
df_target = pd.read_csv(source_file, dtype = None, parse_dates= True, keep_default_na= False,header=None,sep="\|\|",engine='python', encoding='utf-8'))

df_target.to_csv(target_file,header=header_list,index=False,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
...
```

current output:

```
"id","notes"<CR><LF>
"1","notesLine1"<CR><LF>
"2","notesLine1"<CR><LF>
"notesLine2",""<CR><LF>      -- extra unwanted row being created
"3","notesLine1: notesLine2"<CR><LF>
```

note the row is split into two, amking total rows to have 4 rows. I dont want this to happen!

expected output:

```
"id","notes"<CR><LF>
"1","notesLine1"<CR><LF>
"2","notesLine1 \n notesLine2",""<CR><LF>
"3","notesLine1: notesLine2"<CR><LF>
```

note: instead of split into two rows, I can have '\n' and data within same row. so that total rows are 3 and not 4.

Is there a way that this can be handled?

Answer (score 1):

CR and LF are control characters, respectively coded 0x0D (13 decimal) and 0x0A (10 decimal).

They are used to mark a line break in the file.

Comment: Thanks, but how is this information useful for the problem I asked for ?

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps :

```
with open("sample.csv", 'r+') as file:
    text = str();
    for line in file:
        
        if line[0].isdigit() == True:
            text = "{}\n{}".format(text, line.strip())
        else:
            text = "{} {}".format(text, line.strip())
    file.seek(0);
    file.write(text[1:])
```

[image: Sample File input and output Screenshots][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhKtp.png)

Comment: If  you want '\n' explicitly, replace the else statement as below 
```    else:
              text = "{} \\n {}".format(text, line.strip()); 
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This works, However, it is dependent on the First Charcter of Line, and checking if its digit. This may fail if there is an alphanumeric. How Can I Manage that ? Note that 'ID' column can have Alphanumeric like - 'ts001' also. Can I use some split logic and check alpha numeric ?